# Reuse of USB after ubuntu installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu

This might seem like a stupid question but...

After using a USB to install Ubuntu, is it possible to use it as a regular USB again or is it like a CD install and the USB is now only good for installing Ubuntu?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

Infact you can keep the Ubuntu setup as it is and use the remaining free space to store other things, just incase you need Ubuntu installation in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it normally, just be sure you have cleaned up the MBR for the case you leave the device plugged in at restart (when USB boot is still enabled).

Easiest is to format the whole partition (or use a partition manager to clean up the whole device). [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/index.php) should be able to do this for you.

Some (sketchy!) technical background:

The USB device is a flash device, where bits are stored non-volatile, but eraseable and changeable. Bits at a normal CD-ROM will really be "burned" in as the reflection capacity will be permanently changed when creating a CD. When booting up your computer, there is small memory ROM that contains a bootloader, that is looking up for devices containing a MBR at the first 512 bytes, that will be executed and load the OS (or in your case the first steps of the Ubuntu installation process).

So if you want to use the USB device as normal data storage again, you should also clear up these first 512 Bytes, as the bootloader from the USB could be loaded otherwise when leaving the device plugged in at reboot. Then the bootloader could throw an exception, as it would normally expect the Ubuntu installation files to be present onto this device.